# Adding WCF Restful service to an existing ASP.Net Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I am trying to add a wcf restful service to my existing asp.net 4.0 website (not mvc). I am finding hard time trying to find a good tutorial that walks through in adding one to an existing app/website. Everywhere I see there are notes on creating a new project (with wcf restful template).
What are the basic steps? can I do this without an .svc file since I am on .net 4.0? Any tutorial you can point me to?

So far i've tried adding a IService.cs and Service.cs classes that define service contracts and uses webinvoke/webget attributes, added routes in global.asax and service definitions in web.cong as shown in this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/255684/Create-and-Consume-RESTFul-Service-in-NET-Framewor but when I point to localhost/restservice, I get 404 not found.

update:
This is what I have in my config file. Note that is an existing wcf soap based service.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="migrationServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="migrationHttpBinding" maxBufferSize ="104857600" maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name ="Site.Web.WebService.MigrationService" behaviorConfiguration="migrationServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="migrationHttpBinding"
                  contract="Site.Web.WebService.IMigrationService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Can you post your config file? Also how are you hosting your application is it on IIS or running on cassini for the moment?

Comment: Please post your config file and have you made sure that you have added the route table entry as suggested by @Marc_s below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need any `*.svc` file for a WCF REST service - you can activate it using a `ServiceRoute` - see [RESTful WCF Services with No svc file and No config](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/08/21/restful-wcf-services-with-no-svc-file-and-no-config.aspx) for a great explanation.

Basically what it boils down to is adding a `ServiceRoute` to your route table in `global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("", new WebServiceHostFactory(), 
                                           typeof(YourService)));
}
```

Comment: I do have this in my routes but results in 404...  protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("RestService", new System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Site.Web.WebServices.Service)));
        }

Comment: Your service contract (the interface) should have an attribute something like `[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/test")]` or something like that. That would define the URL to connect to - e.g. `http://yourserver/test` - what does it say in your case?? This is **NOT** determined by the first parameter of the `ServiceRoute` constructor (`RestService` in your example)!

Comment: I put it as [WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]

Comment: @xoail: then try to connect just to `http://site.com` - does that invoke your service? If not: try setting an `UriTemplate = "/test"` or something like that on your service contract and connect to `http://site.com/test` - does that work??

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether you can do without svc file.Adding svc file is not  abig deal.Just click add new item and YourServiceName.svc .In the sc file enter the following code:-

```
<%@ServiceHost Service="YourNamsespace.YourWCFservice"%>
```

.net 4 may come with easy ways to add the svc file directly

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
 {
     protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
         RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(YourService)));
   }
 }
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid adding it so that my URIs look cleaner like site.com/restservice/getdata instead of site.com/restservice.svc/getdata ...

Comment: You can use routing tables in .net 4 to avoid it.You can add the changes in global.asax file